# Connecting to SQL Server in Windows using Mono

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, ssl, mono

I have never worked with Mono before.
I have written a sample project and I try to connect to a SQL Server but I am getting an error that says `"TLS Support is not available"`.
I am running the program on Windows. When I run the same program on Linux it is working fine beucase `ca-certificates-mono` is intalled.

here's the connectionstring that I am using to connect to database :

```
var connectionString="Server=192.10.10.211,1433;Initial Catalog=mobile;user=usr;pwd=pwd";
```

I couldn't find any information on Mono documentation to show how I should set TLS support for mono on Windows.

Comment: Have you considered using .Net Core which runs on Linux?

Comment: @Crowcoder yes for some reasons Core is not an option.

Comment: This looks like old TLS version issue. Check that your version of Mono and SQL Server support TLS 1.2

Comment: @Alex How should I do that ? I am using latest Mono version and SQL Server 2014( I am also using SQL Server 2016 and I am getting the same error)

Comment: Updated: Some background: a few years ago there was a major security flow discovered in SSL so it was **forcefully** discontinued in favour of TLS. You need to make sure that both client and server support and default to TLS 1.2. SQL Server details: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server